# While calculating self-energy or work required to assemble a continuous charge distribution, do we take the energy of an element with itself?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential-energy, regularization, self-energy

while calculating the self-energy of a continuous charge distribution using the formula

[image]

the potential $V$ here is due to the whole charge distribution but we need potential due complete charge distribution except the element dT(volume element). How is this correct?

On the other case while calculating that for a point charge distribution this formula is correct but clearly here $V(ri)$ means potential due to other charges not the one the with we are multiplying the potential as the it would give infinite potential

---

[image]

Comment: Related/Duplicate? [Energy of a Continuous Charge Distribution](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/714557/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually for a continuous distribution of charge, you get the same result in both case. Indeed, the field is proportional to the charge that it generates, so the field generated by the vanishingly small charge $\rho d\tau$ vanishes.

There is another connection between the two formulas. If your discrete distribution of $n$ charges $\rho_n(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n q_i\delta^{(3)}(r-r_i)$ converges to a continuous distribution $\rho$, then you have the convergence of the energies:
$$
W_n = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n q_i V_i \\
W = \frac{1}{2}\int \rho V d\tau \\
W_n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} W
$$

The convergence of charge density is to be understood in the weak sense (if you're familiar with distributions), namely for "any" function $f$:
$$
\int \rho_n f d\tau \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \int \rho f d\tau
$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now I also found this in griffiths electrodynamics "Now, you may wonder where the inconsistency crept into an apparently watertight derivation. The “flaw” lies between Eqs. 2.42 and 2.43: in the former, V(ri)
represents the potential due to all the other charges but not qi , whereas in the
latter, V(r) is the full potential. For a continuous distribution, there is no distinction, since the amount of charge right at the point r is vanishingly small, and its
contribution to the potential is zero. But in the presence of point charges you’d
better stick with Eq. 2.42."